# Python TKinter - Reloading frame to change the values of label

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, stopwatch

I've been working on a Stopwatch project with UI. I built the UI using my novice skills in TKinter. I am trying to find a way to change the text of the label which prints the new time every second.

My first idea was to reload the frame every time the text is supposed to change and repack it and run it to the mainloop. Is there a way to do this, or is there another way it is possible to achieve this?

I had tried to do this using the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as t

hour = 0
minute = 0
second = 0


ptime = [hour, minute, second]

time = ':'.join(ptime)

window = tk.Tk()


window.title("Stopwatch")


###window.minsize(250,250)
###window.maxsize(500,500)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.geometry("250x120")

window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
window.iconbitmap("clock.ico")

timeLabel = tk.Label(window, text = time, font = (None, 40))

running = False

def resetf():
    print("Stopwatch Resetting")
    ptime = [str(0), str(0), str(0)]
    time = ':'.join(ptime)
    timeLabel.config(text = time)
    timeLabel.pack()
    print("Stopwatch Reset")
def tgl():

    global running
    
    if running:
        print("Stopwatch Ending")
        print(running)  
        running = False
        print(running)
        print("Stopwatch Not Running")
    elif not running:
        print("Stopwatch Starting")
        print(running)
        running = True
        print(running)
        print("Stopwatch Running")
    
            


startstop = tk.Button(window, text = "Start/Stop", command = tgl)
startstop.config(width = 250)
reset = tk.Button(window, text = "Reset", command = resetf)
reset.config(width = 250)



timeLabel.pack()

startstop.pack()
reset.pack()

window.mainloop()

while running:

        t.sleep(1)
        second = second + 1
        
        if second == 60:
            minute += 1
            second = 0
        if minute == 60:
            hour += 1
            
        ptime = [str(hour), str(minute), str(second)]
        time = ':'.join(ptime)
        timeLabel.config(text = time)
        timeLabel.pack()
        
        window.mainloop()
```

This is my entire code so far. What should I change to make it so that every second the label's text changes?

Comment: You can use the `configure` method on a label to change the text without having to refresh the whole window. There are many questions on this site about creating clocks and timers, you should seek them out. One thing they all have in common is to tell you not to use `sleep`. Instead, use the `after` method available on all widgets.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Oakley, it works beautifully well.